# POST data to php using vanilla javascript and get it back

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send variable to php using javascript and trying to receive back and alert that variable. But `$_POST['data']` doesn't get a data that I pass and `$obj` is always null.

If I just `echo "some text";` it alerts that.

Here is my javascript code:

```
getMessageType('some data'); //function call

function getMessageType(str)
{
    data = {'key': str};
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "test.php";
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    console.log(data); //Object {key: "some data"}
    xhr.send(data);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php       
$obj = $_POST['key'];
echo $obj;
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: it's a string `some data` which I am passing when I call `getMessageType` function. you can see at top of code.

Comment: You're not providing any sort of key called `data`, so there's no way to retrieve the value by that key if you never set that key.  Perhaps the string is in the POST body instead of the key/value pairs?

Comment: I still get blank alert even after setting the key.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard no there aren't any errors. and yes I am running it on apache.

Comment: What does the request/response look like?

Comment: Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 19 Jul 2017 14:40:30 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=97
Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21

Comment: Are you seeing the data you're supposed to send?

Comment: no I don't see that.

Comment: That's your problem. Add `console.log(data);` just before the send to make sure it is populated.

Comment: I have corrected my mistake what @cale_b and David said. here is console log result `Object {key: "some data"}`. but still I am unable to get data back. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Please check my updated question and help me out.

Comment: And no, you don't just `echo $obj;`, you `echo htmlspecialchars($obj);` to avoid HTML injections.

Answer (score 1):

You are posting the data with the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Therefore your data must be **form encoded** :

```
data = "key="+str;
```

You can check this in your browser if the POST info has any "form data"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass JSON data (object) having **content-type** *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* you need to convert it in text format:

```
  var params = "";
    for (key in data) {
        params += encodeURIComponent(key)+"="+encodeURIComponent(data[key])+"&";
    }
```

and then send it

```
xhr.send(params);
```